# How to put element into multiple categories in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

For example,

input.csv is as follows:

| Song Name | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 7 Rings | 'dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop' |
| Run | 'dance pop', 'piano rock', 'pop', 'pop rock' |
| Dance Monkey | 'australian pop', 'pop' |
| All Of Me | 'neo soul', 'pop', 'pop soul', 'r&b', 'urban contemporary' |

I want to group it in a way where I can get something like:

```
pop: ['7 Rings', 'Run', 'Dance Monkey', 'All Of Me']
dance pop : ['7 Rings','Run']
r&b: ['All Of Me']
```

And even put this into another table/dataframe/csv like:

| pop | dance pop | r&b | neo soul | pop rock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 Rings | 7 Rings | All Of Me | All Of Me | Run |
| Run | Run |  |  |  |
| Dance Monkey |  |  |  |  |
| All Of Me |  |  |  |  |

Is there anyway to do this?

Edit:

trying out mozway's suggestion, I got a table that would look like this instead:

```
genreExplode=df.explode('Genre').assign(index=lambda d: d.groupby('Genre').cumcount()).pivot(index='index', columns='Genre', values='Song Name').fillna('')
genreExplode.head()
```

| Genre | 'dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop' | 'dance pop', 'piano rock', 'pop', 'pop rock' | 'australian pop', 'pop' | 'neo soul', 'pop', 'pop soul', 'r&b', 'urban contemporary' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| index |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 7 Rings | Run | Dance Monkey | All Of Me |

Edit 2:

Figured out the problem, the objects in the Genre column looked like lists, but were actually strings.

```
genrelist=df['Genre'].tolist() ##first make a list of the Genre column
genrelist_new=[] ## new list to hold lists

import ast ## found this online
for x in genrelist:
    x=ast.literal_eval(x) ##this loop takes the string objects that look like list in genrelist and converts them into list
    genrelist_new.append(x) ##then add the converted list and put into a list

df['Genre']=genrelist_new ##replace old Genre column of strings that look like lists to new column of real lists
genreExplode=spotData.explode('Genre').assign(index=lambda d: d.groupby('Genre').cumcount()).pivot(index='index', columns='Genre', values='Song Name').fillna('')
genreExplode.head() ## this result is what I was looking for!
```

Solution, convert the strings into real lists, so that Genre column is a list of lists.

Then @mozway's code works flawlessly.

Comment: Also the genres in the original csv column are put in square brackets like ['pop','rock','dance'], but I can't show it because it triggers the warning that my code isn't properly formatted even though it is not code.

Comment: Consider putting your solution in an answer instead so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Genre" contains lists (*e.g.*, `['dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop']`). You can `explode` and `pivot`:

```
(df.explode('Genre')
   .assign(index=lambda d: d.groupby('Genre').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='index', columns='Genre', values='Song')
   .fillna('')
)
```

output:

```
Genre australian pop dance pop   neo soul piano rock           pop pop rock   pop soul post-teen pop        r&b urban contemporary
index                                                                                                                             
0       Dance Monkey   7 Rings  All Of Me        Run       7 Rings      Run  All Of Me       7 Rings  All Of Me          All Of Me
1                          Run                                 Run                                                                
2                                                     Dance Monkey                                                                
3                                                        All Of Me
```

Comment: I copied and ran your code, not sure if I missed anything, but I got a table of each song name only occuring once, and the column titles are the whole list of genres rather individual genres in the list.

Comment: @RiBoFen I didn't get the full comment, please post code/output in the question

Comment: @Corralien luckily I have you to watch over my typos ;)

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: I think I have an idea of why it doesn't work, i think the objects in the genre column aren't recognised as lists even though they look like lists in square brackets, so perhaps I need to change the type into list first?

Comment: Can you give the output of `df.to_dict()`?